# Stop javax.swing.JOptionPane from printing log to the output

Tags: java, swing, logging, netbeans, joptionpane

```
package dataindi;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int id;
        id = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nEnter id:"));
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code with `JOptionPane`, it will start printing logs on the output.

How can I stop it? Below is the output when I try to run the class.

run:
[2022-03-18T00:11:52.695] [INFO] ThreadId: 1 ThreadName: main JAVA BRIDGE CONSTRUCTOR.
[2022-03-18T00:11:52.698] [INFO] ThreadId: 1 ThreadName: main os.arch: amd64
[2022-03-18T00:11:52.701] [INFO] ThreadId: 1 ThreadName: main LOADING lib: 
Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.UIAutomation.Java.Bridge.Native
[2022-03-18T00:11:52.707] [INFO] ThreadId: 1 ThreadName: main >>> Adding listener.
[2022-03-18T00:11:52.762] [INFO] ThreadId: 1 ThreadName: main windows.length: 0
[2022-03-18T00:11:52.761] [INFO] ThreadId: 18 ThreadName: Thread-3 NamedPipe Server is created
[2022-03-18T00:11:52.981] [INFO] ThreadId: 20 ThreadName: AWT-EventQueue-0 ####### WINDOW EVENT: windowActivated class javax.swing.JDialog Input
[2022-03-18T00:11:53.005] [INFO] ThreadId: 20 ThreadName: AWT-EventQueue-0 ####### WINDOW EVENT: windowOpened class javax.swing.JDialog Input
[2022-03-18T00:11:55.174] [INFO] ThreadId: 20 ThreadName: AWT-EventQueue-0 ####### WINDOW EVENT: windowDeactivated class javax.swing.JDialog Input
[2022-03-18T00:11:55.181] [INFO] ThreadId: 20 ThreadName: AWT-EventQueue-0 but is visible

Comment: Seems more like a problem to do with the logging API or the IDE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I updated an RPA software recently which I believe is related to this log "[2022-03-18T00:11:52.701] [INFO] ThreadId: 1 ThreadName: main LOADING lib:
Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.UIAutomation.Java.Bridge.Native" do you know why this will affect the NetBeans java application output??

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I find out that the same problem exist in different IDE

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by deleting Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.UIAutomation.Java.Bridge.Native from the accessibility.properties file @AndrewThompson thanks for giving the hint(API logging)